# MSAccess - Measure Actual Record Width (characters)?

Tags: ms-access

I am assisting to manage a data resource sitting on a SQL server (1.3M+ records, 125 Columns).  The data model is fixed in its current state, though a handful of columns were added in the past month.

I have a DB app that copies a subset records from the primary table into a local table to let users efficiently review/edit, then write back the updated records to the server.  Been working well since 2013. Typical subset is 3K to 10K records.

```
SELECT dbo_TblMatchedTb.* INTO TblMatchedTb
   FROM dbo_TblMatchedTb
   WHERE (((dbo_TblMatchedTb.INVID)=11339));
```

This week, while creating the local "copy", I saw an error for the first time:

```
"Record Too Large - err 3047"
```

Inspecting the dataset produced via the statement above (in a CSV export), I found 7 records MUCH longer than average.  These records were 2087 chars wide, vs 1500 chars ave (including the CSV commas)

Via a bit of manual iteration, I was able to copy over the records when the max record width was shortened to < 1907 chars.

**Question:**

Is there an efficient method/query to measure the current total record width in the local table described above?  (3K to 10K records, 125 columns).  If I can ID records approaching some limit, I can TRIM several candidate data values (i.e.,from 255 to 100 char).

I can't touch the schema, but I can conditionally shorten some of the less than critical data values.

Any ideas?

Comment: Only way I can see is to use Len() function on each field and add the results. Perhaps you can narrow this down to specific fields causing issue.

Comment: June7, that's not a terrible idea.  There are ~8 description fields, all set to 255 chars.  I can more easily monitor these and truncate the least important if the combined length in > X.  Much different task than looking at 125 columns!  -thx

Comment: What happens if you change field type to Long Text? Or if users don't really need to review those fields, exclude from download. I think you would have to test length of each field individually or don't bother testing, just automatically truncate.

Comment: I have zero control of the schema, sadly.  I do think i'll inspect only selected attrs, when the sum is greater than some number, then I can TRIM a couple to 100 chars.

Comment: Can't do what you want with local table?

Comment: This is a rare issue, with 7 non-compliant records since 2013 among 1.3M total records. Data came form a single client with very robust descriptions.  Normaly the ERPs we deal with are in rage of 30, 60, 90 chars.